# Does Seedborn Muse untap Time Vault

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Time Vault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTime%20Vault%5d) has the following ability:

> Time Vault doesn't untap during your untap step.

Is [Seedborn Muse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSeedborn%20Muse%5d) able to untap Time Vault?

Comment: Compare "Time Vault doesn't untap during **your** untap step." and "Untap all permanents you control during **each other player's** untap step."

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

[Time Vault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTime%20Vault%5d) only prevents itself from being untapped during its controller's untap step. It doesn't hinder attempts to untap it at any other time.

There's a ruling about this on [Seedborn Muse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSeedborn%20Muse%5d):

> Other effects can prevent a permanent from untapping during an untap step. You do need to look carefully, however, as many effects say that the permanent does not untap during its controller’s untap step, and this card’s ability occurs during other players’ untap steps. If a card does say this, then Seedborn Muse can untap it. But some other abilities are not written this way and can still prevent a card from untapping.

Comment: Trivia: Seedborn Muse's ability isn't a triggered ability. It can't be, because noone gets priority during the untap step. (Abilities that trigger during the untap step would get added to the stack in the upkeep step.) Instead, it's a static ability that creates a continuous effect that modifies the rules.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, that is more accurate. All static abilities create continuous effects, and some continuous effects change the rules.

Comment: I don't know if relevant cards exist to ask this about... but does Time Vault's "doesn't untap" ability only affect the normal game rule for untapping during your untap step, or does it prevent other effects from untapping it during your untap step? So if Seedborn Muse instead said "untap all permanents you control during each player's untap step", would you untap Time Vault during your own untap step?

Comment: @GendoIkari,Re "*does it prevent other effects from untapping it during your untap step?*", Effects can't untap during the untap step. That's why Seedborn Muse modifies the rules instead. And yes, Time Vault prevents the rules from untapping it during the untap step, no matter what the rules currently are. The ruling from Seedborn Muse says as much. ("Other effects can prevent a permanent from untapping during an untap step.")